# How to upgrade from React.JS 0.14.6 to React.JS 16.12.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think this is farfetched, but would this even be possible, realistically feasible or is a complete new build just copying in my component structure more realistic?

It seems what me and my colleagues have inherited is a bit of a mess to begin with. Sorry if this is not too specific. The feeling of despair when I saw the repo was real, this is my first gig out of a bootcamp

Nothing in the React docs about something this extreme.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "dom-tools": "^0.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.6",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-pace": "^1.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0",
    "redux": "latest",
    "redux-saga": "latest"
  }
```

Comment:  Good luck, you made my day 
 I'll suggest going with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and adapt the rest for it. Depending of your webpack config, this may be easy or not at all.

Comment: This question is a matter of opinion.   Mine is...  if you don't already have unit tests, write them first, then move over to the new packages and fix until your tests pass.  Good luck!

Comment: agree, test your app so tests passes at the end, either unit test or E2E test.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks. Yeah there are no unit tests to be found yet so I guess we get a bit of a free pass there almost. We have been cleaning up style and file structure first but shall start writing some tests to ensure nothing breaks during the upgrade process. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the experience above it is best to create a new 'create react app' copy of the project and migrate your code across. It is a lot quicker than iterating through such a large number of previous versions one by one; including needing to familiarize yourself with the breaking changes in each.

Although the knowledge of limitations of past versions can be useful it is unlikely to be of great utility, let alone memorable enough to retain. Save yourself a lot of time: jump forward and repair what breaks as needed.

Comment: this is a true answer, but honestly you'l likely encounter a no win scenario and just have to rewrite it.